# Many unknown "Frame xxxxx-xxxxx" files. Do you know what these are and can I delete them?

Tags: macos, disk-space

Asking for a friend on a more recent if not most recent Mac OS.

He has a whole bunch of files taking up a bunch of space.  These files are numbered, not necessarily incrementally and named "Frame" followed by a 5 or 6 digit number, a dash and another 5 or 6 digit number.

Example filenames:
"Frame 75776 - 76799"
"Frame 290816 - 291839"

These files are in the "Documents" folder, take up a quite few dozen Gigabytes if I understand correctly and are identified by the OS as type "TextEdit.app Document"
All have the same datestamp (and relatively similar/kind of seqeuntial timestamps) and they are all 101.7 MB in size.

I'm assuming some kind of temp file or something that wasn't cleaned up properly but idk from what.  Google isn't turning anything up and I would like to be sure before I advise he can delete them.

Anyone know what these are, how they might have come to be and if it's safe to just delete?

Thanks much.

EDIT - I should add that the contents of the files do not appear to be text as the 'type' implies.  They seem to be some kind of binary blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 'friend' uses FinalCut or Motion, they may be created by these apps.

See this [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7675476) thread.

Comment: LOL. I know those "Friend" questions, thanks for the chuckle.  I'm a Windows user and support and admin Windows systems but as "computer guy" I'm expected to know all things :)  
I know a bit about Mac OS (enough to get around and basic troubleshooting) and a bit more about Linux but not a whole lot about either.

I will check with him about these two though I don't think so.   Link was at least somewhat helpful, thank you.

Comment: Usually the Frame xxxxx-xxxxx files are stored in folders FCP creates in its Library structure and aren't usually seen by the user. Sometimes users do odd things ;-) and the files become visible elsewhere.

Comment: Turns out the user did install a trial/demo of Final Cut at one point and timeframe lines up with Frame files' timestamp.  idk why these are in his Documents folder but that is how they appear.  Anyway, thank you, solved and answer accepted.